# .NET C# convert ResourceSet to JSON

Tags: c#, json

I would like to create a JSON object from a Resource File (.resx). I converted it to a `ResouceSet` as such:

```
ResourceSet resourceSet = MyResourceClass.ResourceManager.GetResourceSet(CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture, true, true);
```

I now have a set of objects in the form `{Key:<key>, Value:<value>}` but would instead like to convert it to JSON in the form or a hash map `{Key:Value, ...}`.

Comment: Do you just want the JSON of `resourceSet` however it gets serialized or do you want to have more control over it?

Comment: Is your resource set guaranteed to only contain text, or does it contain images / icons as well?

Comment: Resource only contains text.

Comment: @TheGreatCO I want hash map serialization. I can serialize as a object `{Key:<key>, Value:<value>}` but that's not what I want.

Comment: @MartinDrapeau If you check out SharpExtensions.Json on NuGet, you'll find some helpful C# Extension methods for working with Json.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Since `ResourceSet` is an old collection class (HashTable) and uses `DictionaryEntry`, you need to convert the resourceSet to a `Dictionary<string, string>` and use Json.Net to serialize it:

```
resourceSet.Cast<DictionaryEntry>()
           .ToDictionary(x => x.Key.ToString(),
                         x => x.Value.ToString());

var jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(resourceSet);
```

Answer (score 0):

I liked Karhgath's solution but I didn't want to use Json.Net since I had a list with the key/value pairs already.  So to build on Karhgath's solution I just looped through the dictionary:

```
public static string ToJson(ResourceManager rm) {
    Dictionary<string, string> pair = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    ResourceSet resourceSet = rm.GetResourceSet(CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture, true, true);

    resourceSet.Cast<DictionaryEntry>().ToDictionary(x => x.Key.ToString(), x => x.Value.ToString());

    string json = "";

    foreach (DictionaryEntry item in resourceSet) {
        if (json != "") { json += ", "; }
        json += "\"" + item.Key + "\": \"" + item.Value + "\"";
    }

    return "{ " + json + " }";
}
```